# how to create a build of materials in Node/Typescript

Tags: npm

I am new in the Typescript world, and would like to know, is there any way to create a "build of materials" in Typescript, to update the versions of services easily?
for example I have this dependencies in package.json:

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.43.3",
    "ts-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "typescript": "^3.7.2",
    "webpack": "^4.41.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.9.0"
 },
```

Is there a way to create something like this:

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "@types/googlemaps": "${google.version}",
    "ts-loader": "${tsloader.version}"....
 },
```

just to avoid to go in each project and update one by one

Comment: What would those "google.version" or "tsloader.version" be? If you have to define them somewhere else, you just moved the problem somewhere else.

Comment: Besides, this has nothing to do with typescript, it's all about npm.

Comment: My thinking is, if I import a build of materials, I could just update its version and everything would be in the lastest version

Comment: But what do you mean by "a build of materials"? The version numbers on `package.json` is precisely the versions of libraries you require. Having them there or on another place is pretty much the same, with an extra indirection. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: In Java we use maven, and we would have all our dependencies in a maven bom, and the pom from each project, would use the version specified in the bom. That is what I am trying to do.

Comment: That's precisely what the fragment of `packages.json` does. For each library it tells what version do you want. Change these and you can update them. Why do you need something different?

Comment: because we have hundreds of projects, and it is kind of a pain to update each dependency from each project every time.